# how to reverse/reset code (given below) of dock click minimizing?

Tags: command-line, minimize

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize'
```

after using this dock clicking minimizing command, now when i have more windows open and click on the dock to view and choose the windows IT ALWAYS MINIMIZES AND MAXIMIZES LAST WINDOW! what is the REVERSE /RESET COMMAND?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `reset` command.

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action
```

This will reset the `click-action` key to the original default.